# Why wont my {% extends %} command work in my django app

Tags: python, django

I am making a web app with django, and in one portion I am trying to make use of the {% extends %} command to put some html from one template on to another. Here is the code:

home.html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 {% block content %}
 {% endblock %}
</body>
</html
```

search.html -

```
{% extends "gamelobby/home.html" %}
{% block content %}
 <h1>Hello World</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Code for home.html view -

```
def index(request):
    all_games = GameCard.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('gamelobby/home.html')
    context = {
        'all_games': all_games,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: You haven't told us what doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess and say that you still reference `home.html` in the view... Please try to create an [mcve]

Comment: @solarissmoke no I do not get an error its just none of the html from search.html shows up

Comment: Show us the code in your view that calls the template.

Comment: @solarissmoke there i added the view code for home.html

Comment: The view is calling `gamelobby/home.html`. Nowhere is it calling `search.html` - so why would that template be loaded?

Comment: @solarissmoke the tutorial I followed did not mention this being necessary, what exactly do I do to fix this

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to happen is to direct people to your search `view` so that view has to know about `search.html`

```
def index(request):
    all_games = GameCard.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('search.html') <!-- or whichever file -->
    context = {
        'all_games': all_games,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

When this view loads the template, it sees this `extends` from `gamelobby/home.html` and pulls it in *around* the block tags.